# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Can't get this to work. I downloaded a distribution cert but it stil gives me this problem. Also, organizer says that there aren't any valid identity or profile pairs.

Comment: For codesign error,you must have to install proper keychain file (.p12 Extension) in you machine. you can export it from organizer but you can only import it machine from where certificate requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify below steps to create distribution certificate and perform that if you miss anyone.
1) Generate a certificate signing request in keychain.
2) Using that create or revoke a DISTRIBUTION certificate in the portal. after that download and install it and verify key under the name.
3) Register the device in the provisioning portal.
4) Then create or modify a DISTRIBUTION profile in the portal. after that download and install it and verify it appears to be valid in Organiser as there are no warnings.

Make sure to select proper build setting in xcode.

Comment: what is the proper build settings?

Comment: Like if you have distribution certificate with some identifier EX. com.xyz.abc then you must have to set it in info.plist file and same in code sign identity in build setting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I use Application Loader(Version 2.5.1(235)) to upload my app which compiled in Xcode 4.2.

But when I used Xcode4.2's Archive, it's validated and successfully submitted.
I don't know why.